# Seg fault when string copying into a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory, dynamic

In my program I have a global struct:

```
struct card{
   char* action;
   // and other irrelevant members
   };
```

and a function that initializes each card to default values:

```
void initializeCard(card* cards){
  char* charPtr;
  (*cards).action = new char[9];
  charPtr = (*cards).action;
  *charPtr = 'a'; 
  charPtr++;
  *charPtr = 'c';
  charPtr++;
  *charPtr = 't';
  charPtr++;
  *charPtr = 'i';
  charPtr++;
  *charPtr = 'o';
  charPtr++;
  *charPtr = 'n';
  charPtr++;
  *charPtr = '\0';   

  // so on for other members
  }
```

In main, the initialization function is called for the unshuffled deck of "cards":

```
card* unshuffled = new card[108];
for(int i=0;i<108;i++, unshuffled++){
   initializeCard(unshuffled);
   }
```

Later on, I'm trying to overwrite the "action" string for a card in the array with a string that has been brought in from a file (the file is valid; I wrote it myself). The string that is coming in is a maximum of 8 characters, so it WILL fit into the already-allocated action array.

```
  fin >> temp;
  stringCopy((*cards).action, temp); // <---- this is where I get the seg fault
```

StringCopy is my own version is strcpy that simply copies character by character up to and including the null char. I've tested it to work properly.

Why am I getting the seg fault?

Also, don't question why I did things the way I did; I am doing this for a class and must use dynamically allocated memory, must write my own string library functions, cannot use vectors, arrow operator, or overloaded operators.

Comment: Then at least use your own `stringCopy` function. Initializing strings the way you do is tedious, hard to read and prone to errors.

Comment: Can you at least use `[]` on the arrays? `new` gives you the `unshuffled` array, but then you increment the pointer in the loop. Do you ever reset the pointer back to the beginning of the array?

Comment: I've tried and tried to create a function that can take in string literals, but can't find a solution that doesn't involve methods that we are allowed to use or that I have been taught and can understand.

Comment: The only difference between a `char*` variable and a string literal is that the string literals are read-only. That's it. Passing a string literal as the source of your string copying function (which should be of type `const char*` anyway) should work fine.

Comment: I am only allowed to increment pointers using ++, but I did forget to reset them back. Problem solved. It's been a long night. Thanks for the obvious solution.

Comment: If you're forced to do pointer arithmetic maybe `(unshuffled+i)` is allowed.

Comment: thanks for a well formatted question. Good luck!

Comment: Or use a temp ptr and increment it through the loop, but retain your original allocation ptr. I.e. `card* tmp = unshuffled; for (int i=0;i<108;initializeCard(tmp++),i++);` Or as Adam said, `for (int i=0;i<108; initializeCard(unshuffled + i++));`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for letting me know about this. I never thought it would actually work but had never tried it out. Works correctly.